# can an audio unit's inputcallback provide ima4 compressed data

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiounit

I have loading an Ima4 databuffer and would like to play it.
I have an inputcallback setup for linear pcm but logically this doesnt work with ima4 data. Is it possible to write an inputcallback which provides ima4 data to a converter which then converts to linear pcm?
Currently I have some idea of how I would try to write this callback but I'm quite unsure wether I can actually do this, so any tips would be welcome.

Comment: did you find a solution yet? I am facing the same problem, pulling my hair now.